# Listen change on Filefield in extjs

Tags: file, extjs, extjs4.1

I want listen when file has been change like. But It not working

```
{
            xtype: 'filefield',
            id: 'form-file',
            fieldLabel: 'Photo',
            name: 'photo-path',
            buttonText: '',
            buttonConfig: {
                iconCls: 'upload-icon'
            },
            listeners: {
                  'change': function(this, value){
                        alert('change');
                  }
            }
}
```

Comment: I found solution: function change must be: change: function(f,new_val) {
           alert(new_val);
        }

Comment: IF you solved your own problem, please post it as an answer (and accept you own answer)

Comment: @tcaswell okay thank u :) I just post my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution: function change must be:

```
change: function(f,new_val) { alert(new_val); }
```

Comment: `new_val` is just a string which (at least on chrome) is just a string which starts with `c:\fakepath` so I don't think this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with filefield of Extjs

I have the solution.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e3M3e/e8V7g/

```
var itemFile = null;
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 400,
    html: "<input id='inputFile' type='file' name='uploaded'/>",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            itemFile = document.getElementById("inputFile");            
            itemFile.addEventListener('change', EventChange, false);
        }
}
});

function EventChange(e){    
    var files = itemFile.files;
    console.log(files);
}
```